# Java - I cannot view tables in preset mysql databases but can view on user-created databases

Tags: java, mysql, database, tree, jtree

I have a very serious problem with my code, I am working on a database GUI application.
The aim of the app is to provide an interface to manage databases..Its a kinda phpMyAdmin stuff.
I am getting all databases and displaying them on a JTree, upon clicking on each database shows its tables as leaves. My problem now is that all databases are shown with their tables as expected except for those databases that came with mysql installation I mean (Information_schema, mysql, test, performance_schema..etc). Tables under each of these databases in the bracket are not showing on the Tree, only tables on user-created databases..ie. those databases I created myself.
But the databases that came with mysql installations are showing, but with empty tables each.
I don't know if there's something I've missed in my connection URL.
The possible summary of the code is below:

```
public static Connection getConnection(Database database) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName(database.getDriver()).newInstance();

            Properties property = new Properties();
            property.setProperty("user", database.getUser().getUsername());
            property.setProperty("password", database.getUser().getPassword());

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(database.getUrl(), property);

        } catch (SQLException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }

DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Databases");

        JTree tree = new JTree(root);

        DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();

        try {
            DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = getDatabaseMetaData(database);

            ResultSet resultSet = databaseMetaData.getCatalogs();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode db = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(resultSet.getString("TABLE_CAT"));
            root.add(db);
            getDatabaseTableTree(database, tree, db);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

public static DatabaseMetaData getDatabaseMetaData(Database database) throws SQLException {
        return getConnection(database).getMetaData();
}
```

In my Database class I have the following fields

```
private String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private String databaseName = "";
private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
private User user = null;
private String tableName = "";
```

And also the getter and setter methods for all of them, thats why you see me call the getter and setter methods in the code above..

I hope I've atleast been able to describe my challenge enough for your usual solution.

I choose not to select a database in the URL above since I am going to be working on all databases..

I even ran a test that shows each database name in a dialog box when each database is clicked on, and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a permissions issue.  Root has full access all the system information.  However, individual users are more limited (Quote copied from http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,585682,585683#msg-585683):

> Each MySQL user has the right to access these tables, but can see only
>   the rows in the tables that correspond to objects for which the user
>   has the proper access privileges. In some cases (for example, the
>   ROUTINE_DEFINITION column in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES table),
>   users who have insufficient privileges see NULL. These restrictions do
>   not apply for InnoDB tables; you can see them with only the PROCESS
>   privilege.
>
> The same privileges apply to selecting information from
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA and viewing the same information through SHOW
>   statements. In either case, you must have some privilege on an object
>   to see information about it.

To give a user full access to the all the databases, you could type this (as root, or a user with the "grant option"):

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

Comment: Thanks for such a prompt response. Actually I am the only user for now, so I'm using the root user account with the password I configured for it..meanwhile I'll try to grant the privileges again even though I did it when I set a password for the root account.

Comment: Let me know if it doesn't work, but it seems right in line with your issue, especially if you see the databases.

Comment: Yes I have done it but still no way, it said 0 rows affected. I even opened the user table to view and realized that the root user currently has all privileges, and on all tables.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing some details.  Here's what I'd assume... if you log into mysql via the normal client, "mysql -u root", you'll see all the information you want.  Then, if you access the same mysql server from your app, and you provide "root" for the username and the root password (as in, you confirm, with a breakpoint/print statement that you are passing in exactly this to JDBC), you should have access to all the tables, and all the rows.  I'd suspect something like what you're talking about if the credentials were not passed in correctly, and it's just connecting as an unprivileged user.

Comment: Okay I really understand what you mean now. In that case, please look at my code above and tell me how to genuinely login to the server. Cause I think you're right. This is how I did the connection.   connection = DriverManager.getConnection(database.getUrl(), property);

Comment: Please put a `System.out.println("username=["+database.getUser().getUsername()+"]");` just before you create the "Properties property" object.  Same for the password, although you might not want to copy and paste the output from that.

Comment: I have done that and it gives me [username=root] [password=mydatabasepassword] which are the exact details I entered during login

Comment: (Just to make sure the root user is not screwy)  You're able to login via "mysql -u root", with that same password, then "use information_schema;" and then you can see all the data you're expecting?

Comment: You're saying you're getting the list of databases successfully, correct?  So you're sure you're passing the correct database names to the "getDatabaseMetaData" method?  If so, then I'd say the problem would be in the getDatabaseMetaData method... that was something you wrote, correct?  It might not be accessing the database correctly.  Maybe you'd want to add details about what's inside it.

Comment: thanks for your concern..I have added the getDatabaseMetaData() to the question above, I hope it'll help my chances of getting helped.

Comment: I have found the error, the problem was with the getTable() method, I wrote it this way ResultSet resultSet = databaseMetaData.getTables(null, null, "%", types) that was why it didnt show the tables under preset mysql databases, I changed it to ResultSet use = statement.executeQuery("USE " + database.getDatabaseName()), then ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SHOW TABLES"), but I don't like it this way cos mysql documentation says its not good, I wish I can get the getTable() method to work, don't know what to put as catalogName and schemaPattern to make it work..